# How do we prove that, if A∼B then P(A)∼P(B)?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

"∼" means Equipotence i.e there exists a bijective function between A and B 
So I can't hancle the relation between the equipotence and the power set...

Also I'm trying to prove that if  A∼X and B∼Y then A × B ∼ X × Y

Comment: A bijection between $A$ and $B$ will naturally induce a bijection between their power sets. (Please include your thoughts about your question. Also, please only ask one question per post.)

Comment: Im sorry, my problem is how to stablish that "naturally induced bijection"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

From a bijection $f:A\longrightarrow B$, you deduce instantly  a map
\begin{align}
F:\mathscr P(A)&\longrightarrow\mathscr P(B),\\
X\subset A&\longmapsto Y=f(X)\subset B.
\end{align}
You just have to show it is a bijection, e.g. finding its inverse map.

For the product of two sets, similarly, from bijections $f:A\longrightarrow X$ and $g:B\longrightarrow Y$, you deduce a map, denoted $f\times g$, defined thus:
\begin{align}
f\times g:A\times B &\longrightarrow X\times Y,\\
(a,b) &\longmapsto \bigl(f(a),f(b)\bigr),
\end{align}
for which you can find an inverse map.